# Locked out of SQL Server Reporting Services 2016

Tags: reporting-services

Grabbed an old Windows 10 laptop with SQL Server 2016 Developer Edition installed to use with a demo. Despite my account being in the machine's Administrators group, I don't have access to objects in reporting services e.g., reports, folders, KPI's, etc. access via Report Manager. Argh!

I know report credentials are stored in the ReportServer database. Where do you go to add users for SSRS itself?

Environment...

- Chrome v60.0.3112.113
- Windows 10 v10.0.15063 Build 15063
- SQL Server 2016 SP2

Message I receive is as follows:

> You are not allowed to view this folder. Contact your administrator to
>   obtain the necessary permissions.

Here is a screen shot...

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ugh! So stupid.

I had been using Chrome v60.0.3112.113 for Windows. I had launched Chrome as an administrator. I decided to give Microsoft Edge a try. When I launched Edge, it prompted me for creds. At first, I tried my "regular" account, which is in the administrators group on the host. Then I created a local user, added it to the administrators group, and used that. That worked. Once I was in, I granted myself site permissions.

Other things I tried....

1. From SQL Server Installation Center, running repair from the Maintenance page. Did nothing. It was more like a cry for help.
2. Uninstalled SQL Server Reporting Services then installed and configured it again. I was left with the same issue.
3. Prayer. I actually found this helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Can you get to the Report Portal?  Remember, even if you are setup as an administrator, you still have to grant rights to each individual folder, including the home folder.
If the admin group wasn't removed, you should still see it in site settings:
[image]

once you are in there, you then need to add yourself to the home folder.  navigate to the home folder and click manage folder (see top right).  Make sure your Id or the Builtin/administrators role has access to the folder:
[image]

One other thing to check.  You can see what users are on the system (if any) if you have access to the ReportServer database:

```
SELECT TOP (1000) [UserID]
  ,[Sid]
  ,[UserType]
  ,[AuthType]
  ,[UserName]
  ,[ServiceToken]
  ,[Setting]  FROM [ReportServer].[dbo].[Users]
```

Comment: Yup, I can get to the portal. When I'd pull up the landing page, I'd see a message telling me I didn't have access.